# Como passar o conteúdo de JSON Objeto para um controller

Tags: angularjs

Como faço para passar o conteúdo do objeto JSON do service para controller.

No momento faço testes com os seguinte códigos:

> Controller(app.js)

```
  example.controller('equipecontrol', ['EquipeService','$scope', function( EquipeService,$scope) {      

Parse.initialize('APPLICATION_ID', 'JAVASCRIPT_KEY'); 
Parse.serverURL = 'https://parseapi.back4app.com';

EquipeService.$inject = ['EquipeService']; // Injetamos o service

equipes =  { "nomejogador": '',
             "posioriginal":'',
             "nomedotime": '',
             "jogoude": ''
            };

listaobjEquipes = EquipeService.listaobjEquipes;   <--- NESTE MOMENTO O OBJETO ESTÁ RETORNANDO VAZIO

...
```

> Service(service.js)

```
var example = angular.module('starter')
example.service('EquipeService', ['$http', function($http) {
  var aDadosEscalacao = {};
  return { listaobjEquipes: aDadosEscalacao,
        get: function(param) {
          var nteste = 1
          if (neste = 1) {
            idjogador = '1';
            idtime = '1';
            idjogoude = '1';
            idpelada = '1';
            ngolsjogador = '207';
            faltastxtJSON = '1';
            ncrtamarelos = '1';
            ncrtvermelhos = '1';
            nptoscraque = '18';
            nptosdestaque = '19';
            nptosmaster = '21';
            nptosgoleiro = '12';
            aDadosEscalacao = { "idjogador": idjogador, 
                                "idtime": idtime,
                                "idjogoude": idjogoude,
                                "idpelada": idpelada,
                                "gols": ngolsjogador,
                                "faltas": faltastxtJSON,
                                "cartao_amarelo": ncrtamarelos,
                                "cartao_vermelho": ncrtvermelhos,
                                "pontuacaocraque": nptoscraque,
                                "pontuacaodestaque": nptosdestaque,
                                "pontuacaomaster": nptosmaster,
                                "pontuacaogoleiro": nptosgoleiro };
          }
          return aDadosEscalacao
        }
  }
}])
```

Pergunto, o que há de errado no código que não consegue passar o conteúdo do JSON 
preenchido para o controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem alguns problemas nessa função. Se for utilizar o `$http`, que você injeta mas não usa, você terá problemas de assíncronia, mas vamos focar no problema atual.

Você está utilizando um método do seu service que simplesmente retorna o valor da variável `aDadosEscalacao`. Como você definiu um objeto vazio, ela simplesmente retorna esse objeto.

Para retornar o valor correto, você precisa executar o método `get` que você definiu, que nesse caso preenche a variável e retorna com o valor correto.

Basta alterar

```
listaobjEquipes = EquipeService.listaobjEquipes;
```

Para:

```
listaobjEquipes = EquipeService.get();
```

Comment: Ok Leandro, funcionou apenas implementando o get() como você orientou. Gostaria de deixar também registrado outra forma que foi feita e funcionou também: foi seguindo orientações do vídeo postado neste link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2_k4ECZrTI o código ficou assim ...  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2_k4ECZrTI e no controller listaobjEquipes = EquipeService.getEscalacao(); Resolvi deixar registrado apenas para acrescentar o nosso banco de conhecimento. Em resumo acho sua resposta legal, pois não preciso alterar nada no service.js, apenas no controller. Obrigado mais uma vez!

Comment: boa tarde! após esta solução encontrada, editei meu códigos e implementei instruções de parse.query no service.js, o metodo que estou usando agora é o getEscalacao, no entanto o mesmo não consegue transmitir o conteúdo do objeto aDadosEscalacao para o controller.

Comment: @Ita abre uma outra questão com o código completo e atualizado lá. Fica mais fácil de entender o problema.

Comment: Já fiz, segue o link http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193295/como-passar-um-conte%c3%bado-de-json-objeto-para-um-controller-parte-2-usando-par