# Como passar um conteúdo de JSON Objeto para um controller - Parte 2 - Usando Parse.Query

Tags: angularjs

Desculpem por volta praticamente no mesmo tópico, mas agora quando utilizo uma Parse.Query para obter meus dados no service.js, não  estou conseguindo passar o JSON com conteúdo para o controller(app.js),  segue abaixo trecho dos códigos. service.js

```
var example = angular.module('starter')
example.service('EquipeService', ['$http', function($http) {
  var aDadosEscalacao = {};
  this.getEscalacao = function(params) {

            Parse.initialize('APPLICATION_ID', 'JAVASCRIPT_KEY'); 
            Parse.serverURL = 'https://parseapi.back4app.com';

            var EscalacaoObject = Parse.Object.extend("Escalacao");
            var Escalacaoquery = new Parse.Query(EscalacaoObject);

            if(params !== undefined) {
              if(params.idPeople !== undefined) {
                  Escalacaoquery.equalTo("jogador", params.idPeople);
              }        

              if(params.idPosicao !== undefined) {
                  Escalacaoquery.equalTo("jogoude", params.idPosicao);
              }        

              if(params.idEquipe !== undefined) {
                  Escalacaoquery.equalTo("time", params.idEquipe);
              }        

              if(params.idEvento !== undefined) {
                  Escalacaoquery.equalTo("pelada", params.idEvento);
              }        
            }

            Escalacaoquery.find({
                    success: function(results) {
                        //console.log("Em Escalacao, achamos " + results.length + " jogadores escalados!");

                        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

                            var object = results[i];

                            var jogadortxtJSON = JSON.stringify(object.get("jogador"));
                            var jogoudetxtJSON = JSON.stringify(object.get("jogoude"));
                            var timetxtJSON = JSON.stringify(object.get("time"));
                            var peladatxtJSON = JSON.stringify(object.get("pelada"));
                            var golstxtJSON = JSON.stringify(object.get("Gols"));
                            var faltastxtJSON = JSON.stringify(object.get("faltas"));
                            var crtamarelotxtJSON = JSON.stringify(object.get("cartao_amarelo"));
                            var crtvermelhotxtJSON = JSON.stringify(object.get("cartao_vermelho"));
                            var ptoscraquetxtJSON = JSON.stringify(object.get("PontuacaoCraque"));
                            var ptosdestaquetxtJSON = JSON.stringify(object.get("PontuacaoDestaque"));
                            var ptosmastertxtJSON = JSON.stringify(object.get("PontuacaoMaster"));
                            var ptosgoleirotxtJSON = JSON.stringify(object.get("pontuacaogoleiro"));


                            idtxtjogador = JSON.parse(jogadortxtJSON);
                            idjogador = idtxtjogador.objectId                //id do jogador
                            idtxtjogoude = JSON.parse(jogoudetxtJSON); 
                            idjogoude = idtxtjogoude.objectId                //id jodou de ...
                            idtxttime    = JSON.parse(timetxtJSON);  
                            idtime = idtxttime.objectId                      //id da Equipe/Time
                            idtxtpelada  = JSON.parse(peladatxtJSON); 
                            idpelada  = idtxtpelada.objectId                 //id da pelada/evento. 
                            ngolsjogador = JSON.parse(golstxtJSON);          //Quantidade de Gols do Jogador
                            faltastxtJSON = JSON.parse(faltastxtJSON);       //Quantidade de Faltas do Jogador
                            ncrtamarelos = JSON.parse(crtamarelotxtJSON);    //Quantidade de Cartões Amarelos
                            ncrtvermelhos = JSON.parse(crtvermelhotxtJSON);  //Quantidade de Cartões Vermelhos
                            nptoscraque = JSON.parse(ptoscraquetxtJSON);     //Quantidade de Pontos para eleição do Craque
                            nptosdestaque = JSON.parse(ptosdestaquetxtJSON); //Quantidade de Pontos para eleição Destaque
                            nptosmaster = JSON.parse(ptosmastertxtJSON);     //Quantidade de Pontos para eleição Master
                            nptosgoleiro = JSON.parse(ptosgoleirotxtJSON);   //Quantidade de Pontos para eleição Goleiro

                            aDadosEscalacao = { "idjogador": idjogador, 
                                                "idtime": idtime,
                                                "idjogoude": idjogoude,
                                                "idpelada": idpelada,
                                                "gols": ngolsjogador,
                                                "faltas": faltastxtJSON,
                                                "cartao_amarelo": ncrtamarelos,
                                                "cartao_vermelho": ncrtvermelhos,
                                                "pontuacaocraque": nptoscraque,
                                                "pontuacaodestaque": nptosdestaque,
                                                "pontuacaomaster": nptosmaster,
                                                "pontuacaogoleiro": nptosgoleiro };
                        }
                        return aDadosEscalacao
                    },
                      error: function(error) {
                          alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                      }
            });
  }
}])
```

> trecho do controller(app.js)

```
example.controller('equipecontrol', ['EquipeService','$scope', function( EquipeService,$scope) {      
    equipes =  { "nomejogador": '',
                 "posioriginal":'',
                 "nomedotime": '',
                 "jogoude": ''
                };
```

`listaobjEquipes = EquipeService.getEscalacao();` <-- ESTÁ RETORNANDO O OBJETO VÁZIO

Não sei se é o ponto de onde eu estou colocando o return, mas a verdade é  que o o JSON está chegando vazio no controller, qual o procedimento que  devo adotar para conseguir passar o JSON com conteúdo para o controller?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como passar o conteúdo de JSON Objeto para um controller](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193120/como-passar-o-conte%c3%bado-de-json-objeto-para-um-controller)

Comment: Por favor, não utilize formatação de citação desnecessáriamente.

Comment: Alguém tem alguma ideia como eu posso solucionar este caso?

Comment: @leandrooriente, Dando continuidade em meus testes, verifiquei que quando uso o find() o objeto volta a passar vazio para o controller, tem alguma ideia de solução neste contexto?

Comment: Alguém consegue dar uma luz?

Answer (score 2):

Eu acredito que o método getEscalacao() que você está chamando no controller, é uma função assincrona (Por conta da função Escalacaoquery.find(...) ser assincrona) e o return está dentro da função de sucesso do método find. Portanto, quando o método getEscalacao() é chamado no seu controller, ele ainda não está preenchido.

```
    var example = angular.module('starter')
example.service('EquipeService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
  var aDadosEscalacao = {};
  this.getEscalacao = function(params) {
             var deferred = $q.defer();
            Parse.initialize('APPLICATION_ID', 'JAVASCRIPT_KEY'); 
            Parse.serverURL = 'https://parseapi.back4app.com';

            var EscalacaoObject = Parse.Object.extend("Escalacao");
            var Escalacaoquery = new Parse.Query(EscalacaoObject);

            if(params !== undefined) {
              if(params.idPeople !== undefined) {
                  Escalacaoquery.equalTo("jogador", params.idPeople);
              }        

              if(params.idPosicao !== undefined) {
                  Escalacaoquery.equalTo("jogoude", params.idPosicao);
              }        

              if(params.idEquipe !== undefined) {
                  Escalacaoquery.equalTo("time", params.idEquipe);
              }        

              if(params.idEvento !== undefined) {
                  Escalacaoquery.equalTo("pelada", params.idEvento);
              }        
            }

            Escalacaoquery.find({
                    success: function(results) {
                        //console.log("Em Escalacao, achamos " + results.length + " jogadores escalados!");

                        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

                            var object = results[i];

                            var jogadortxtJSON = JSON.stringify(object.get("jogador"));
                            var jogoudetxtJSON = JSON.stringify(object.get("jogoude"));
                            var timetxtJSON = JSON.stringify(object.get("time"));
                            var peladatxtJSON = JSON.stringify(object.get("pelada"));
                            var golstxtJSON = JSON.stringify(object.get("Gols"));
                            var faltastxtJSON = JSON.stringify(object.get("faltas"));
                            var crtamarelotxtJSON = JSON.stringify(object.get("cartao_amarelo"));
                            var crtvermelhotxtJSON = JSON.stringify(object.get("cartao_vermelho"));
                            var ptoscraquetxtJSON = JSON.stringify(object.get("PontuacaoCraque"));
                            var ptosdestaquetxtJSON = JSON.stringify(object.get("PontuacaoDestaque"));
                            var ptosmastertxtJSON = JSON.stringify(object.get("PontuacaoMaster"));
                            var ptosgoleirotxtJSON = JSON.stringify(object.get("pontuacaogoleiro"));


                            idtxtjogador = JSON.parse(jogadortxtJSON);
                            idjogador = idtxtjogador.objectId                //id do jogador
                            idtxtjogoude = JSON.parse(jogoudetxtJSON); 
                            idjogoude = idtxtjogoude.objectId                //id jodou de ...
                            idtxttime    = JSON.parse(timetxtJSON);  
                            idtime = idtxttime.objectId                      //id da Equipe/Time
                            idtxtpelada  = JSON.parse(peladatxtJSON); 
                            idpelada  = idtxtpelada.objectId                 //id da pelada/evento. 
                            ngolsjogador = JSON.parse(golstxtJSON);          //Quantidade de Gols do Jogador
                            faltastxtJSON = JSON.parse(faltastxtJSON);       //Quantidade de Faltas do Jogador
                            ncrtamarelos = JSON.parse(crtamarelotxtJSON);    //Quantidade de Cartões Amarelos
                            ncrtvermelhos = JSON.parse(crtvermelhotxtJSON);  //Quantidade de Cartões Vermelhos
                            nptoscraque = JSON.parse(ptoscraquetxtJSON);     //Quantidade de Pontos para eleição do Craque
                            nptosdestaque = JSON.parse(ptosdestaquetxtJSON); //Quantidade de Pontos para eleição Destaque
                            nptosmaster = JSON.parse(ptosmastertxtJSON);     //Quantidade de Pontos para eleição Master
                            nptosgoleiro = JSON.parse(ptosgoleirotxtJSON);   //Quantidade de Pontos para eleição Goleiro

                            aDadosEscalacao = { "idjogador": idjogador, 
                                                "idtime": idtime,
                                                "idjogoude": idjogoude,
                                                "idpelada": idpelada,
                                                "gols": ngolsjogador,
                                                "faltas": faltastxtJSON,
                                                "cartao_amarelo": ncrtamarelos,
                                                "cartao_vermelho": ncrtvermelhos,
                                                "pontuacaocraque": nptoscraque,
                                                "pontuacaodestaque": nptosdestaque,
                                                "pontuacaomaster": nptosmaster,
                                                "pontuacaogoleiro": nptosgoleiro };
                        }
                       deferred.resolve(aDadosEscalacao);
                    },
                      error: function(error) {
                          alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                     deferred.reject(error);
                      }
             return deferred.promise
            });
  }
}])
```

Então, no seu controller você faz:

```
    listaobjEquipes = EquipeService.getEscalacao().then(function(escalacao){
        //Do whatever you like
}, function(error){

});
```

Comment: Marcelo, bom dia! também fiz as alterações como você citou no código acima, porém no controller não está surtindo efeito ... EquipeService.getEscalacao().then(function(escalacao){
      console.log('não apresenta este log')
     }, function(error){

    });

Comment: Marcelo, boa noite! antes do then, listei apenas listaobjEquipes = EquipeService.getEscalacao(); depois fiz um listatxtEquipes = JSON.stringify(listaobjEquipes); e o resultado obtido foi {"$$state":{"status":0}}, porém na região de "//Do whatever you like" o console.log() não apresenta absolutamente nada, aliás, o log nem executa, você tem alguma ideia do que possa está acontecendo? como eu devo proceder para conseguir passar o conteúdo do JSON aDadosEscalacao.

Comment: Marcelo, bom dia! você tem alguma ideia de como eu poderia resolver?

Answer (score 0):

O `Parse`retorna uma `promise`.

O primeiro passo é retornar essa `promise`na chamada dessa função. Se você não der um `return` nela, a `promise` se perde dentro da função.

Para acertar isso basta alterar a seguinte linha:

```
Escalacaoquery.find({
```

para:

```
return Escalacaoquery.find({...
```

Com a `promise` sendo retornada, você ainda precisa tratar o retorno dela de forma adequada.

As `promises` são assíncronas, ou seja, saem da pilha padrão de execução do seu código e rodam em paralelo. Logo, você não consegue receber o objeto diretamente para adicionar em uma variável. Você precisa pegar esse resultado no retorno da `promise` com o método `then`.

Para isso basta mudar o seu código para:

```
EquipeService.getEscalacao().then(function(dados) {
  // Faça o que quiser com os dados que retornaram da promise.
  funcaoQuePrecisaDosDados(dados);
})
```

Tenha sempre em mente que tudo que estiver fora do `then`, vai ser executado antes do retorno da `promise`, logo você não vai ter acesso aos dados.

Para trabalhar em cima dos dados que você recebeu, só utilizando dentro do `then` ou chamando uma função dentro dele e passando como parâmetro.

Comment: bom dia! fiz as alterações conforme você passou, mas no controller não está tendo efeito ...                                                              EquipeService.getEscalacao().then(function(escalacao){
      console.log('não apresenta este log')
     }, function(error){

    });

Comment: bom dia! tem alguma ideia de como eu poderia resolver?